# Book recomendations for Smooth manifolds.

Tags: reference-request, manifolds

I want to learn about smooth manifolds, I have never studied them before, but I have a good background in Algebra. Can any one recomend some good introductory books?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out *[Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441999817)* by John Lee, *[Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0121160513)* by William Boothby and *[Differentiable Manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/081764766X)* by Lawrence Conlon.

Comment: Lee's book seems very good.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments.  I just want to point out that the PDF that @amWhy linked to is a very early (and very buggy!) draft of the first edition of my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_, which somehow managed to escape into the wild and has now been posted on a number of sites in violation of copyright.  Download it if you want, but _caveat emptor_.  The published first edition is more reliable, and the second edition is much better.  Just so you know.

Comment: @JackLee Thanks for your caveat! Good to know! I will, at once, delete my comment with the link - impressive as it was, even if buggy, as you say. I did not know that there was a violation of the copyright!

Comment: Here's a link to [Lee's book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds.html?id=eqfgZtjQceYC), for anyone interested...

Comment: [Springer link](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5/page/1). Perhaps useful to someone